# Sidescrolling jittery when changing directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, parallax

I made my own sidescrolling parallax using jQuery and the mousewheel plugin. It's working great so far except for the fact that when I change directions of the scroll, it jitters first before actually scrolling (as though it's scrolling one unit to the previous side before actually moving to the correct one). I've tried adding a handler for this which supposedly stops the scroll completely.

Here is my script so far:

```js
var scroll = 0; // Where the page is supposed to be
var curr = scroll; // The current location while scrolling
var isScrolling = false; // Tracker to check if scrolling
var previous = 0; // Tracks which direction it was previously
var loop // setInterval variable

function parallax() {
  isScrolling = true;

  // Loops until it's where it's supposed to be
  loop = setInterval(() => {
    if ( curr - scroll == 0 ) {
      clearInterval(loop);
      isScrolling = false;
      return;
    }

    // Move the individual layers
    $('.layer').each(function() {
      $(this).css('left', -curr * $(this).data("speed"));
    });

    // Add/subtract to current to get closer to where it's supposed to be
    curr += (scroll < curr) ? -0.5 : 0.5;

  }, 25);
}

$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.scrolling-container').mousewheel((e, dir) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // If the speed's magnitude is greater than 1, revert it back to 1
    if ( Math.abs(dir) > 1) {
      dir = Math.sign(dir);
    }

    // If the direction changes, stop the current animation then set scroll to where it currently is
    if ( previous !== dir ) {
      previous = dir;
      isScrolling = false;
      scroll = curr;
      clearInterval(loop);
    }

    // If not at the left most scrolling to the left, add to scroll
    if ( scroll - dir >= 0 ) scroll -= dir;

    // Call parallax function if it's not yet running
    if ( !isScrolling ) {
      parallax();
    }
  })
})
```

I think it's easier to show so here's a codepen of the functional parts: https://codepen.io/ulyzses/pen/yLyoYZm

Try scrolling for a while then change direction, the jittery behaviour should be noticeable.

Comment: Have you tried using the `transform` property instead of the `left` property for the animation? `left` causes the entire document to be recalculated and repainted, `transform` however will only cause a repaint on the transforming element as it is pulled into its own paint layer. And when using a value like `translate3d` you get GPU acceleration, meaning: mo powah, baby!

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I'll keep that in mind, thanks!